# Installation of mactex under mojave 10.14.5 failing

Tags: mactex

I'm new to Mac Mojave but not to macs or software.  The Pkg file from MacTex does  not respond to double-clicking or to pressing click, then pressing the "install" button.  Can anyone suggest how to get this to run?  My computer is a macbook pro 2018 and I'm downloading with Safari.  Thank you kindly for any help.  I did look at your "similar questions" but they don't seem to be the same.  Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You could try installing in the terminal (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72226/installing-pkg-with-terminal), then you might get an error message that helps you to identify the problem. One possibility is that the download was corrupted, see https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html under _Installation Errors_ on how to verify the integrity of the file.

Comment: That sound like you may have a bad download.

Comment: Thanks, Marijn and Herb.  I did try using terminal and then repeated with a new download.  Also other downloads  (e.g., Mathematica) have come through without difficulties.  TeX failed on my old Mac after I updated the Mac OS but this is a new box with very little software.

Comment: This is a very un-Mac thing to do but try downloading after a reboot. I'm also reporting the problem.

Comment: Try Get Info (select the pkg file and then Cmd-I). it should be opened by Installer.app.